# how to get top level group name in project pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Currently, I'm working on Gitlab. As part of my task I need to display group id, projectid, runas, job id and job name etc..  in gitlab ci pipeline. I was able to display all required values **except group id**. searched in google to identify default variables for parent ( top-level-groups) but no luck. Can anyone help me with this?

Please don't mind that I'm not posting my pipeline link.

looking for suggestions .. please help me.

**Note: Not looking API based suggestions**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try the value of `CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE` variable.

Comment: Thank you Murli, I was able to get the URL of main group where my project resides.

Comment: was looking for parent group name, not the root so this work for me `${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE#*/}`, if the project name is `/parent-group/sub-group/my-project`, it will return `sub-group`

Answer (score 0):

`$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE` should be either the group, or the user name if it is a private project. GitLab uses the name `namespace` for this both in the variables and through the API, but it makes it a bit harder to find if you are looking for `group`.

Here are all pre-defined variables in GitLab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html